# Java correct order of operations

Tags: java

I have written this operation on paper and it works just fine. I know that java the execution is from left to right and the precedence is like this; * / + - .

Java gives me a different result, but i cant figure out why.

```
public double overTimeWage() {
    if (hours > 40) {
        return (40 * baseRate) + (1.5 * baseRate)
                * (hours - 40);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Here's the inputs I'm using

```
int hours = 50;
double baseRate = 12;
```

as it stands it currently returns 660 , my expected return is 180.

I know this is the correct mathematical formula is because i worked it on paper. and i get 180 out of it.

Comment: What are you expecting, and what are you getting? Also, what value of hours are you using, as all depends on this value? Also, what debugging have you done? Have you run this with a debugger?

Comment: Please give an example, including values of all variables used in the calculation, and tell us how you calculate the results that you expect.

Comment: At your service. All we ask is that you be quick in improving this question so that it's answerable, which again depends on pre-existing conditions, expected outcomes and observed outcomes. My prediction is that your assumptions of pre-existing conditions are wrong.

Comment: every time i hit enter to advance to a new line, this text box assumes i want to submit my comment.

Comment: What's with the down-votes? -- you've hastily posted an unanswerable question.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, then use a "poor-man's debugger": sprinkle the code with System.out.println statements, printing out the values of hour, baserate, and seeing which if block is entered, etc...

Comment: I like that idea.

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. Where are those variables located? What happens if you replace the variables with their actual values in that method?

Comment: How did you manage to get 180? I've tried adding and removing parentheses and all I can get are either 660 or numbers much higher than that, which indicates to me that you might be doing your work wrong and the program is returning exactly what it's being told to.

Comment: `40 * 12` is 480. You add and multiply on top of that. How do you get 180? Please show your paper math

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question but rather a basic math question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

660 is the expected return value. Your problem is that you added in an extraneous piece of the puzzle.

Judging by the name of your method, `overTimeWage`, it's supposed to calculate the amount of overtime of the worker, which is `(overtimeMult * baseRate) * (hours - standardHours)`. In your case, `(1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40)`.

The mathematical calculations go as follows:

```
(1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40)
(1.5 * 12      ) * (50    - 40)
(18            ) * (10        )
18 * 10
180
```

So we got the right answer, right? So why is your method returning 660 and not 180? Here's the thing, your method doesn't return `(1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40)`. It returns `(40 * baseRate) + (1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40)`.

See the problem? You're not returning the overtime earnings. You're returning **their earnings for the whole day**. Just to be clear, let's put this together again:

```
(40 * baseRate) + (1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40)
```

We already know that `(1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40) = 180`.

```
(40 * baseRate) + 180
(40 * 12) + 180
480 + 180
660
```

**660**. And there's your problem. It's the classic issue of code doing what you *tell* it to, not what you *want* it to.

Comment: Might want to recommend renaming the method to `getWage`, then the `else` statement would return the non-overtime wage

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, that might be one way to go but I personally think it'd be better form to have a two methods, one for getting the standard hours earnings and one for the overtime earnings, then assemble that in a separate getTotalWage method.

Comment: Sure, that's another, more granular, option.

Comment: so i was adding another 480 with ( 40 * baseRate ) to my calculation, when i only needed to calculate the overtime, using -- (1.5 * baseRate)*(hours - 40). Fantastic!! way to mess up some math from my part.

Comment: i have three total methods guys, baseWage, overtimeWage and a totalWage. I have two different cases, one wehere i need to show only a wage based on 40 hours, and one where i need to show overtime hours added to the 40 hours. That is why i decided to do 3 methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the overtime:

```
return (1.5 * baseRate) * (hours - 40);
```

The way it's written for you, you're returning the ENTIRE pay, not just the overtime.